# Include "http://" in this PHP URL shortening code

Tags: php, url, href

This is the code I currently have. How would I tweak it to include `http://` in the `href` in the returned result every time? Currently, `http://` is not in the returned result unless it's in the original string variable `$text`. I wish to have it added to the `href` if it is not in the original `$text`. Thanks!

```
function urlfixer($text){

   $pattern  = '#\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#';
   $callback = create_function('$matches', '
       $url       = array_shift($matches);
       $url_parts = parse_url($url);

       $text = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
       $text = preg_replace("/^www./", "", $text);

       $last = -(strlen(strrchr($text, "/"))) + 1;
       if ($last < 0) {
           $text = substr($text, 0, $last) . "&hellip;";
       }

       return sprintf(\'<a rel="nofollow" href="%s">%s</a>\', $url, $text);
   ');

   return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $text);
}
```

Comment: You can't just append it to the beginning when you return from the your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't know if your $url has http:// on it or not just stick it on the beginning, and then make sure it's stripped just in case.

```
$url = 'http://' . str_replace('http://','',$url);
return sprintf('<a rel="nofollow" href="%s">%s</a>', $url, $text);
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach but it's probably a bit safer to only replace occurrences of `http://` at the start of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url       = array_shift($matches);
if( substr($url,0,6)!='http://' ) {
    $url='http://'.$url;
}
```

something like this should do it